# How to Toggle Switch - Prices and Config?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, togglebutton

Need your help:

according to http://ghinda.net/css-toggle-switch/ you can use switch. After reading (as i'am not an full expert) how can I change my price according to definition:

```
     <div class="switch-toggle switch-5 switch-candy yellow">
      <input id="alusa" name="view" type="radio" checked>
      <label for="alusa" onclick="">USA</label>

      <input id="aluk" name="view" type="radio">
      <label for="aluk" onclick="">UK</label>

      <input id="alin" name="view" type="radio">
      <label for="alin" onclick="">India</label>

      <input id="altr" name="view" type="radio">
      <label for="altr" onclick="">Turquia</label>

      <input id="alhk" name="view" type="radio">
      <label for="alhk" onclick="">Hong-Kong</label>

      <a class="btn btn-primary"></a>
    </div>

            <div class="title">Economy</div>
            <div id="alusa" onclick="" checked class="price">$3.99 <i>/ per month</i></div>
            <div id="aluk" onclick="" class="price">$6.99 <i>/ per month</i></div>
            <div id="alin" onclick="" class="price">$6.99 <i>/ per month</i></div>
            <div id="altr" onclick="" class="price">$6.99 <i>/ per month</i></div>
            <div id="alhk" onclick="" class="price">$6.99 <i>/ per month</i></div>
```

How can I change price and configs accord the toggle selected?

Thank you :)

Comment: You do it just like you would if you weren't using that package. All it does is change the way the buttons look, it doesn't affect the functionality.

Comment: @Barmar so with this I not can change prices and my config for example, HDD space, etc? for diferent locations?I'am ask for a fix, not give a aswer.

Comment: Of course you can. Like I said, you do it the same way that you would if you weren't using the CSS Toggle Switch style. `$(":radio").change(...)`.

Comment: Why do you have `checked` in the first `div`? That attribute only makes sense for a radio button or checkbox.

Comment: You have duplicate IDs. You can't have the same ID `alusa` on both an input and a div.

Comment: @Barmar, please can you give me a help? I have create the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kaaj3/ Thank you alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the IDs from the price DIVs, to get rid of duplicate IDs. I moved these IDs into the class, so that the same class can be used in prices for different products.. Then I used `jQuery` to show only the prices whose class matches the currently selected radio button's ID.

HTML:

```
         <div class="switch-toggle switch-5 switch-candy">
          <input id="alusa" name="view" type="radio" checked>
          <label for="alusa" onclick="">USA</label>

          <input id="aluk" name="view" type="radio">
          <label for="aluk" onclick="">UK</label>

          <input id="alin" name="view" type="radio">
          <label for="alin" onclick="">India</label>

          <input id="altr" name="view" type="radio">
          <label for="altr" onclick="">Turquia</label>

          <input id="alhk" name="view" type="radio">
          <label for="alhk" onclick="">Hong-Kong</label>

          <a class="btn btn-primary"></a>
        </div>

          <div class="clearfix mar_top3"></div>

             <div class="pricing-tables-two">
                <div class="title">Economy</div>
                <div class="price alusa">$3.99 <i>/ per month</i></div>
                <div class="price aluk">$6.99 <i>/ per month</i></div>
                <div class="cont-list">


                        <ul>
                        <li>Unlimited Bandwidth</li>
                        <li>100 GB Space</li>
                        <li>10 Databases</li>
                        <li>Ad Credits</li>
                        <li>1 Free Domain</li>
                        <li>24/7 Unlimited Support</li>
                        <li class="last">100 Email Addresses</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="ordernow"><a href="#" class="button darkgray small align">Order Now</a></div>
            </div><!-- end section -->
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $(".price:not(.alusa)").hide();
    $(":radio[name=view]").change(function() {
        $(".price").hide();
        $(".price." + this.id).show();
    });
});
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/kaaj3/2/)

Comment: Hi, but how can I show other prices? Now not change from the alusa price, and buttons not work :s

Comment: Many Thank @Barmar. I understand now, here for example: <div class="price alusa">$3.99 <i>/ per month</i></div> I have a class and a ID. I do not can have both as the ID already exist on function - <input id="alusa" name="view" type="radio" checked> - again many thanks for help :)